# Set title of form generated by Alfresco's forms runtime

Tags: forms, alfresco

I have object named Payment and in share-config-custom.xml I defined form, everything is set nicely, but I don't know how can I change generic title "Payment" to "Payment Details". Does anyone know how to change that?

Best,
D

Comment: I want to know your Payment in share-config-custom.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [resource bundle](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/content-model-localization.html) in Alfresco were you can fill in the type properties or you could just change the custom model you've defined and change it there.